# Taking random sub-samples from a dataframe

Tags: r, random, sampling

I am looking to take 1000 random sub-samples from this data-frame.....i.e., I want R to randomly select 100 individuals from the data, 1000 times.

```
Taxa Abundance 
159 3
161 45
163 3
165 7
167 44
169 93
171 94
173 16
175 9
177 8
195 8
261 18
263 7
271 22
273 0
285 5
287 12
315 12
317 10
327 6
329 13
331 0
333 14
335 12
337 13
339 8
341 13
343 3
345 0
347 17
349 76
351 10
353 14
355 21
357 8
359 15
361 41
363 361
365 10
367 0
369 276
371 465
373 47
375 23
377 8
379 4915
381 231
383 36
385 25
387 9
389 936
391 890
393 375
395 407
397 7
399 33
401 87
403 166
405 74
407 8
409 8
411 15
413 20
415 7
417 8
419 6
421 6
423 47
425 55
427 0
429 0
431 68
433 33
435 222
437 64
439 125
441 219
443 1369
445 2313
447 7379
449 1782
451 78
453 792
455 1532
457 413
459 1387
461 1889
463 2504
465 1951
467 22
469 466
471 166
473 1664
475 2211
477 486
479 85
481 94
483 391
485 345
487 68
489 51
491 38
493 420
495 136
497 6
499 313
501 332
503 474
505 39
507 46
509 1883
511 504
513 390
515 2109
517 289
519 1080
521 1474
523 14
525 1026
527 762
529 83
531 938
533 596
535 3147
537 2545
539 1813
541 79
543 203
545 187
547 175
549 198
551 683
553 1071
555 63
557 36
559 84
561 124
563 74
565 151
567 8
569 3
571 652
573 2212
575 717
577 263
579 93
581 43
583 90
585 70
587 33
589 78
591 20
593 163
595 12
597 52
599 154
601 110
603 11
605 71
607 51
609 31
611 95
613 115
615 35
617 13
619 54
621 16
623 86
625 421
627 140
629 46
631 88
633 113
635 0
637 309
639 1109
641 420
643 149
645 98
647 286
649 177
651 54
653 554
655 56
657 609
659 1166
661 158
663 17
665 39
667 57
669 28
671 0
673 124
675 279
677 39
679 57
681 179
683 8
685 3
687 16
689 39
691 34
693 21
695 98
697 9
699 7
701 28
703 141
705 0
707 78
709 4
711 164
713 7
715 105
717 127
719 68
721 38
723 43
725 315
727 552
729 60
731 530
733 195
735 0
737 13
739 913
741 23
743 63
745 171
747 78
749 421
751 931
753 14
755 47
757 226
759 284
761 108
763 361
765 82
767 238
769 346
771 99
773 58
775 654
777 1981
779 13
781 86
783 56
785 120
787 87
789 532
791 150
793 126
795 109
797 368
799 82
801 16
803 16
805 45
807 2986
809 33
811 47
813 182
815 30
817 214
819 1062
821 110
823 552
825 0
827 159
829 141
831 51
833 241
835 130
837 661
839 0
841 4
843 3
845 213
847 292
849 91
851 20
853 12
855 43
857 577
859 683
861 43
863 663
865 140
867 458
869 393
871 70
873 72
875 147
877 185
879 126
883 0
885 360
887 11
889 72
891 67
893 70
895 186
897 0
899 0
901 80
903 53
905 45
907 10
911 50
913 12
915 20
917 4
919 4
921 43
923 27
925 15
927 4
929 0
931 7
933 6
935 48
937 14
941 8
943 72
945 0
947 31
949 39
951 0
955 0
961 0
963 39
967 39
971 5
973 8
975 0
977 5
979 9
981 0
983 57
985 13
989 28
995 6
997 3
```

I want the taxa to stay in the same order in each of the permutations. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `df`

```
for (i in 1:1000)
{
  s <- sort(sample(1:nrow(df), 100))
  sub.sample <- df[s,]

  ## do something with sub.sample
}
```